# Use Anchor title instead of image title

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

If I have an image in an anchor, how can I make the title of the anchor appear, and not that of the image element?

I know I could remove the title attribute with javascript,  but I'm hoping there is a simpler solution.

### For example

```
<a title="Anchor Title"><img title="Image Title" /></a>
```

If you hover over the link, it will display "Image Title".

### What I've Tried

With CSS, I thought maybe I could change the z-indexes to push the anchor to the front, or maybe I could display the anchor as a block and give it the width and height of the image.  This did not work.  See JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bozdoz/HAb37/).

I was hoping to find a solution with CSS or maybe HTML.

The reason I want to do this is is that I'm working with Wordpress, spitting out posts and thumbnails.  I want the thumbnails to link to a certain page, and I want to have a universal title for the link, but it is taking the title from the individual thumbnails.  Here's the Wordpress/PHP code:

```
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="Click to see Featured Stories">
<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
</a>
```

Comment: remove the title from the image..? :/

Comment: @popnoodles Wordpress requires images to have titles when you upload them to the media library.  I am hoping to give this to a client (so I don't trust them to upload via FTP and specify images via URL). :)

Comment: what @popnoodles said might work well, afaik only an "alt" is required. Also, it might work if you add `display: block` in your CSS for the link.

Comment: It requiring a title doesn't mean it has to come out in the HTML. steveax already wrote out how to remove it before me.

Comment: there's also such a thing as `pointer-events: none`

Comment: I'd use steveax's answer but EricG is right - pointer-events: none works with your css. http://jsfiddle.net/HAb37/2/ RE alt: Alt may be required but the HTML given doesn't have an alt

Comment: @EricG but that would hide both title to appear.

Comment: I used that in a,img  thanks @popnoodles

Comment: @Lenin Not if you set that property on the image.. I dont even know if it works for titles, it was a loose suggestion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This offers a general solution, disregarding WordPress. CSS prevents the title to show up.

HTML:

```
<a title="Anchor Title">
    <img title="Image Title" src="http://codepen.io/images/logo.png" />
</a>
```

With CSS:

```
a {
  display: inline-block;
}

img {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Result

[image]

See [CodePen example](http://codepen.io/joe/pen/yoBdq)

Comment: CSS is my preferred solution.  Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Pass an empty string in the `title` attribute in the `$attr` array in the [thumbnail](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail#Parameters):

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail', array('title' => '')); ?>
```

Comment: Sounds to me best solution.

Comment: A good solution for Wordpress.  I was looking for a more general solution. +1

Comment: Best solution - my answer is framework agnostic because I don't know anything about WP [luckily!].

Answer (score 2):

Just put a transparent `<span>` over the image, with transparent background and desired title attribute.

**Markup**

```
<a href="#">

    <img title="Image Title" />
    <span title="Div Title"></span>    

</a>​
```

**CSS**

```
img { width:50px;height:50px;background:blue; }
a, img { position:absolute; } 
a { z-index:4;display:block;width:50px;height:50px; }
img { z-index:2; }
​span{
    top:0;
    left:0;
    position:absolute;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;    
    display:block;
    z-index:100;
    background-color:transparent;
}​
```

I just [forked your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MZgym/), works in Chrome at least.

Comment: I was thinking about something like this.  It's really just the order of the elements that's causing one title to take priority.

Comment: This is really poor, considering the quality alternative. But fine. Wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

I think removing the img title attribute is the simplest solution of all.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/hnmuj/

CSS:

```
#foo {
    position:relative;
    display:block;    
}
#foo span {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    z-index:1;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    display:block;
```

}
​

HTML:

```
<a title="Anchor Title" id="foo">
    <span></span>
    <img title="Image Title" />
</a>​
```

Comment: Interesting solution, but the span covers the width of the entire page.  I expect conflicts with other elements on the page.

Comment: Did you set the `a` to be `display:block` and `position:relative`?